# Creating cross platform command-line app (with Qt?)

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

I have no prior experience with Qt however I want to ask this before I dig into trying to make my app.

Is it possible to create cross platform command-line application Qt?

My app would generally consist of the executable that is easy to execute like this:

> $ myapp-tool "arg1" "arg2"

Something like that. And it basically will call a REST server via HTTP request. However I want it to work with Windows, Linux and Mac, can I use Qt to make it?

Comment: Qt is designed to be cross-platform so, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, link below should be useful.

[Qt Documentation - QCommandLineParser](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcommandlineparser.html)